# Nifi: Failed to perform ExecuteSQL due to illegal character in SQL query

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NIFI flow which has

```
...->ExecuteSQL->CovertRecord->..
```

While processing my flow, it gets stuck at `ExecuteSQL` processor. My ExecuteSQL runs a query something like this:

```
select f_id,UDF_MD5('J=iDl47av=L'||foo||'%Xh)R/ljFrp') from bar
```

> ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10]
>   o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL
>   ExecuteSQL[id=5ea0e2b3-0af5-3e47-6d53-964fe8cbf9f7]
>   ExecuteSQL[id=5ea0e2b3-0af5-3e47-6d53-964fe8cbf9f7] failed to process
>   session due to org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character
>   in: udf_md5((('J=iDl47av=L'||foo)||'%Xh)R/ljFrp'));
>   Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec:
>   org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in:
>   udf_md5((('J=iDl47av=L'||foo)||'%Xh)R/ljFrp'))
>   org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in:
>   udf_md5((('J=iDl47av=L'||foo)||'%Xh)R/ljFrp'))

I believe it has to do something with the Avro naming specification for the udf_md5 attribute. May I know the work around for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with alias name for the udf_md5 function column and try to run the query again.

**Query:**

```
select f_id,UDF_MD5('J=iDl47av=L'||foo||'%Xh)R/ljFrp') as udf_md from bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "Normalize Table/Column Names" to true in ExecuteSQL.